# How to change quickfixj charset encoding for logs?

Tags: logging, encoding, wildfly, quickfix, quickfixj

I use quickfixj with wildfly Java EE server. I'd like to have fix logs to be merged with application log. But there is the "^A" delimiter. Is there a way to set encoding to UTF for quickfixj engine? I'll appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't sound like UTF encoding. The "^A" character is SOH, the delimiter between FIX tag=value fields. If you'd like to see a different character you can modify the QFJ logging component to convert the SOH characters to something different (like a "|") before writing the data to the log.

Comment: Yes, you're right. It can't be unfortunately set as a parameter for logger - and that would be a nice feature. Currently (as for version 1.5.3) I think it's hardcoded in FieldMap class in method calculateString.

Comment: If you make the change, you could submit it as a patch to QFJ. I agree it would be a useful feature.

Answer (score 2):

The "^A" character is actually the ASCII SOH (0x01) character, which is what FIX uses as the field separator.  It's just what FIX uses.  It's in the FIX spec.

(Not sure why you think it's a Windows charset character.  It's not.)

It would be trivial to create a small script (perhaps with `sed`) to do a find-and-replace if you really want to replace the SOH characters with something else.

Answer (score -2):

If you prefer sed to tr, tail -f foo.log | sed 's/0x01/|/g' should also work.

Best!
--- Vadim

Comment: better try:

`sed 's/\x01/|/g'`